# What is the Highest Version of PyTorch that can be Built from Source?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

As most of you people already know, the official binary of PyTorch will not work if you have an older GPU. If your GPU has a Compute Capability of 3.0 or 3.5, then you are screwed. In order to use PyTorch with CUDA, you have to build a Torch wheel from source.

However, the official site never tells, what the highest version can be built from source if you own a sm_30 or sm_35 graphic card.

I have an Nvidia GeForce GTX graphic card with a Compute Capability of 3.0 (Kepler sm_30), running on Python 3.8 and cuDNN 7.6.5 in Windows.

**After extensive building and testing process, here is my conclusion.**

> With a Compute Capability 3.0 GPU, the highest CUDA version you can install is CUDA 10.2, and the highest PyTorch version you can build from source is Torch 1.10.2.

In other words, starting from PyTorch 1.11.0 and above, there will be new nccl operators added, and therefore causing nvcc errors during the build process.

Although I am confident that no human being on this planet can ever possibly build PyTorch from source on any versions >=1.11.0 with a CC 3.0 GPU, I'm still open to hear different opinions and criticism from an opposite ideology.

So, what is the highest version of PyTorch you think can be built from source?

```
[10/754] Building CUDA object caffe2\CMakeFiles\torch_cuda.dir\__\aten\src\ATen\native\cuda\ForeachUnaryOp.cu.obj
FAILED: caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ForeachUnaryOp.cu.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\NVIDIA~2\CUDA\v10.2\bin\nvcc.exe -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler -DAT_PER_OPERATOR_HEADERS -DIDEEP_US
E_MKL -DMINIZ_DISABLE_ZIP_READER_CRC32_CHECKS -DONNXIFI_ENABLE_EXT=1 -DONNX_ML=1 -DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx_torch -DTORC
H_CUDA_BUILD_MAIN_LIB -DUSE_C10D_GLOO -DUSE_CUDA -DUSE_DISTRIBUTED -DUSE_EXPERIMENTAL_CUDNN_V8_API -DUSE_EXTERNAL_M
ZCRC -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1 -D_OPENMP_NOFORCE_MANIFEST -Dtorch_cuda_EXPORTS -ID:\Work\C
UDA\Torch\build\aten\src -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\aten\src -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\build -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch -ID:\Work\CU
DA\Torch\cmake\..\third_party\benchmark\include -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\cmake\..\third_party\cudnn_frontend\include -I
D:\Work\CUDA\Torch\third_party\onnx -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\build\third_party\onnx -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\third_party\fo
xi -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\build\third_party\foxi -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\build\include -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\torch\csrc\d
istributed -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\aten\src\THC -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\aten\src\ATen\cuda -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\build\caf
fe2\aten\src -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\aten\..\third_party\catch\single_include -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\aten\src\ATen\.. -I
D:\Work\CUDA\Torch\c10\cuda\..\.. -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\c10\.. -ID:\Work\CUDA\Torch\torch\csrc\api -ID:\Work\CUDA\To
rch\torch\csrc\api\include -isystem D:\Work\CUDA\Torch\build\third_party\gloo -isystem D:\Work\CUDA\Torch\cmake\..\
third_party\gloo -isystem D:\Work\CUDA\Torch\cmake\..\third_party\googletest\googlemock\include -isystem D:\Work\CU
DA\Torch\cmake\..\third_party\googletest\googletest\include -isystem D:\Work\CUDA\Torch\third_party\protobuf\src -i
system C:\Users\Alien\AppData\Local\PyTorch\mkl\include -isystem D:\Work\CUDA\Torch\third_party\XNNPACK\include -is
ystem D:\Work\CUDA\Torch\cmake\..\third_party\eigen -isystem D:\Work\CUDA\Torch\cmake\..\third_party\cub -isystem "
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\include" -isystem D:\Work\CUDA\Torch\third_party\ideep\mkl
-dnn\third_party\oneDNN\include -isystem D:\Work\CUDA\Torch\third_party\ideep\include -isystem "C:\Program Files\NV
IDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\include" -isystem C:\Users\Alien\AppData\Local\PyTorch\magma\include -D_WINDOWS -Xcompi
ler=" /GR /EHsc" -Xcompiler /w -w -Xfatbin -compress-all -DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx_torch --use-local-env -gencode arch=
compute_30,code=sm_30 -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=cc_clobber_ignored,--diag_suppress=integer_sign_change,--diag_suppre
ss=useless_using_declaration,--diag_suppress=set_but_not_used,--diag_suppress=field_without_dll_interface,--diag_su
ppress=base_class_has_different_dll_interface,--diag_suppress=dll_interface_conflict_none_assumed,--diag_suppress=d
ll_interface_conflict_dllexport_assumed,--diag_suppress=implicit_return_from_non_void_function,--diag_suppress=unsi
gned_compare_with_zero,--diag_suppress=declared_but_not_referenced,--diag_suppress=bad_friend_decl --Werror cross-e
xecution-space-call --no-host-device-move-forward --expt-relaxed-constexpr --expt-extended-lambda  -Xcompiler=/wd48
19,/wd4503,/wd4190,/wd4244,/wd4251,/wd4275,/wd4522 -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets --expt-extended-lambda -DCUDA_HAS_FP
16=1 -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16
_CONVERSIONS__ -Xcompiler="-MD -O2 -Ob2" -DNDEBUG -Xcompiler /MD -std=c++14 -DCAFFE2_USE_GLOO -DTH_HAVE_THREAD -Xco
mpiler= -DTORCH_CUDA_BUILD_MAIN_LIB -MD -MT caffe2\CMakeFiles\torch_cuda.dir\__\aten\src\ATen\native\cuda\ForeachUn
aryOp.cu.obj -MF caffe2\CMakeFiles\torch_cuda.dir\__\aten\src\ATen\native\cuda\ForeachUnaryOp.cu.obj.d -x cu -c D:\
Work\CUDA\Torch\aten\src\ATen\native\cuda\ForeachUnaryOp.cu -o caffe2\CMakeFiles\torch_cuda.dir\__\aten\src\ATen\na
tive\cuda\ForeachUnaryOp.cu.obj -Xcompiler=-Fdcaffe2\CMakeFiles\torch_cuda.dir\,-FS
D:/Work/CUDA/Torch\c10/core/SymInt.h(76): error: member "c10::SymInt::MASK" may not be initialized

D:/Work/CUDA/Torch\c10/core/SymInt.h(77): error: member "c10::SymInt::IS_SYM" may not be initialized

D:/Work/CUDA/Torch\c10/core/SymInt.h(81): error: member "c10::SymInt::MAX_SYM_IDX" may not be initialized

D:/Work/CUDA/Torch\c10/core/SymInt.h(84): error: member "c10::SymInt::MIN_INT" may not be initialized

4 errors detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/Alien/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_0000027c_00000000-7_ForeachUnaryO
p.cpp1.ii".
nvcc warning : The -std=c++14 flag is not supported with the configured host compiler. Flag will be ignored.
ForeachUnaryOp.cu
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```